# different regex expressions but actually forbid newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am going nuts on this for a few days now. I have read and tried many previously answered questions close to this topic, I've fiddled with all kinds of expressions on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) (very awesome page BTW) but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I want to do the following in JavaScript/Jquery (this has to do with contenteditable="true" elements where I want to restrict user input).
Some elements are for text input without spaces and allowed numbers (abc1_d-ef), some for free text (abc. d2ef, gh6i? j8kl: mno!), some for integers (123), some for decimals (1,2 / 1.2).
**BUT** I want to always **forbid** a newline character or tab (\n \r \t \f).

So:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(.........);
var text = $("#my-id").html();

var test = pattern.test(text);
// test should be true for correct text / integer / decimal
// but should be false as soon as text contains a newline, tab etc.
```

So basically I'm looking for 4 different expressions:

- letters, numbers, underscore, hyphen
- letters, numbers, spaces, special characters and such
- numbers 0-9
- numbers, comma and dot
- but **none of them** with newline etc.

I hope I could make myself clear.

Comment: why on earth does my question get several downvotes in the very first minute?? Is something wrong with it?

Comment: In my opinion not, upvoted.

Comment: Is your confusion coming from you not anchoring your pattern? `/^\d+$/` will match an integer (and only an integer), for example.

Comment: Like this: [**`^[-,.\w ]+$`**](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4sW0/1) ? This only allows the character (classes) in the class, from start to end, nothing else.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I started using regex not long ago. It seems quite confusing to me. Anyway, yours works nicely for integers.
and ^[\d,\.]+$ seems to work for decimals

Comment: @Jan this returns matches while there are newlines in the text.

Comment: Hmm... You've been going at it for days and haven't come up with a regex to match digits only (for example)... Strange...

Comment: @ClasG yes. somehow I wasn't. I tried all kinds of things but I guess I haven't understood the logic behind it yet. I can match a-z or 0-9 and simple things like that. But +*$? etc. completely escape me so far. And I also freeze when I want to combine conditions like explained. I managed to match all letters, spaces and special chars before, but so far I haven't been able to forbid newline. Just like the pattern Jan suggested.

Comment: All I mean is it's a simple task to search the net for the regex'es you're after. Maybe that's why you've been down-voted. And although regexr is may be a good site, I'd suggest that you try [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rZ7eP1/1). It'll explain the regex in a very good way,

Comment: @ClasG I thought so too. I am a seasoned googler ;) But I couldn't come up with the specific thing... Thanx for the tip. It seems on regexr.com you can't specify your language (JS, php, ...)

Comment: @AurelEngleEngelmann: Not really, no. This was only because of the modifiers to show all your input strings. [**Take them away and it works**](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4sW0/2).

Comment: @Jan Oh, very awesome.. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all your requirements, you can use:

```
^[-,.\w ]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4sW0/2).

Comment: Thank you! This works great for my text fields.
/^\d+$/ and ^[\d,\.]+$ do the job for integers and floats.